# CSS Code not converting to SCSS correctly

Tags: html, css, sass

I am very used to using CSS but I am working on a codebase that is set up for SCSS. I have this input form animation that I would like to use here: https://codepen.io/amotor/pen/eYEJjmZ
The problem is whenever I try to convert the code from CSS to SCSS the focus & valid properties get triggered automatically and the form looks like it should after the user has entered an input. Here is the SCSS code that I generated by pasting my CSS code into this website: https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/
Are there any SCSS pros out there that can see what is wrong with the code. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    .root {
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: sans-serif;

.colAuto {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.form {
  width: 100%;
}

.col input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #595f6e;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.form label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid black;

  &:after {
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
}

.contentName {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.form input {
  &:focus + .labelName .contentName, &:valid + .labelName .contentName {
    transform: translateY(-150%);
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  &:focus + .labelName::after, &:valid + .labelName::after {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

.submitButton {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4e68c7;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #203891,0px 1px 1px #3852b1,2px 1px 1px #203891,1px 2px 1px #3852b1,3px 2px 1px #203891,2px 3px 1px #3852b1,4px 3px 1px #203891,3px 4px 1px #3852b1,5px 4px 1px #203891,4px 5px 1px #3852b1,6px 5px 1px #203891;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 98%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0.6rem 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

&:hover, &:focus {
  background: #3d57b4;
}

&:active {
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #203891,0px 1px 1px #3852b1,2px 1px 1px #203891,1px 2px 1px #3852b1,3px 2px 1px #203891;
  transform: translate(3px, 3px);
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

&:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
}
&:active:after {
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply pasting the css without converting it to scss first? All css is valid scss

Comment: Your SCSS is valid and compiled successfully so I think you need to check your html element structure.

Comment: Yes I have tried to just paste the same CSS code. I also verified that the structure of the HTML elements are exactly the same as in the codepen. The only difference is that the classNames begin with scss. I am not sure what else could be causing this to not work as expected so I thought for sure something weird must be happening when scss tries to compile the code.